# Javascript Slideshow effect

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I be back with problems =)
Basing myself on code for a slideshow that I know works, I replaced the images with square boxes and I'd like for them to each "activate" one after another with a seconds interval. I simply don't get whats wrong with the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MiniAnimation</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            window.addEventListener("load",onLoadWindow);

            var active_slide;
            var slides;

            function onLoadWindow(e) {
                var slideShow=document.getElementById("boxofBoxes");
                slides=slideShow.getElementsByTagName("div");
                active_slide=0;

                slides[0].classList.add("active");

                setInterval(nextSlide,1000);
            }



            function nextSlide () {
                slides[active_slide].classList.remove("active");
                active_slide++;

                active_slide%=5;

                slides[active_slide].classList.add("active");
            }

        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                background-color:lightblue;
            }

            .active {
                opacity:1;
                transition:opacity 1s;
            }

            .box {
                display:block;
                float:left;
                width:25px;
                height:25px;
                background-color:white;
                margin-left:63px;
                opacity:0;
            }

            #boxofBoxes {
                width:503px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="boxofBoxes">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Again, thanks for the help ! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the order your CSS is written in, the `opacity: 0;` is overriding the `opacity: 1;`. Try it like this:

```
.box {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:63px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

You'll have to figure out the opacity transitions and positioning yourself, but hopefully this helps!

Here's a jsFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/sJNvw/

Comment: Yes thanks! I kept transition in .active though like in the original code, just flipped it under the .box style definition as you pointed out. I was under the (false) impression that whatever what being called last would over ride whatever was set initially. Good to know the order of css stylings matter ^^